# How to combine two 1D arrays to a 2D array for plt.imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a finncie graph and show it with `plt.imshow()` my data are two 1D arrays, one for price and the other one for time. I know how to show them using the `plt.plot` method
but I want to show few of them together.
this is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = [6.59, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 7.10, 7.11, 7.12, 7.13, 7.14, 7.15,
        7.16, 7.17, 7.18, 7.19, 7.20, 7.21, 7.22, 7.23, 7.24, 7.25, 7.26, 7.27, 7.28, 7.29,
        7.30, 7.31, 7.32, 7.33, 7.34, 7.35, 7.36, 7.37, 7.38, 7.39, 7.40, 7.41, 7.42, 7.43,
        7.44, 7.45, 7.46, 7.47, 7.48, 7.49, 7.50, 7.51, 7.52, 7.53, 7.54, 7.55, 7.56, 7.57]

close = [42.05, 42.03, 42.05, 42.05, 42.1, 42.1, 42.08, 42.08, 42.08, 42.08, 42.08, 42.08, 42.08, 42.09, 42.09, 42.09,
         42.09, 42.09, 42.09, 42.08, 42.08, 42.09, 42.08, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 42.09, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1,
         42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.13, 42.14, 42.13, 42.13, 42.16, 42.16, 42.15, 42.15, 42.14, 42.14, 42.14, 42.14,
         42.14, 42.14, 42.14, 42.15, 42.15, 42.14, 42.14, 42.15, 42.15, 42.15, 42.14, 42.15, 42.15, 42.15, 42.15, 42.16]
symbols_list = ["BAC","AAPL"]
test_images_list = []

temp_list = [list(a) for a in zip(time, close)]
test_images_list.append(temp_list)
graph_day_array = np.array(test_images_list, dtype=np.float)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(graph_day_array[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(symbols_list[i])
    plt.ylabel(symbols_list[i])
plt.show()
```

But the pictures look 1D (only y ex)

Comment: I am not sure what the 2D aspect would be. You will plot `time` on the x-axis (which is, btw, a list of strings, not datetime objects) and `close` on the y-axis, giving you a line or scatter plot.  If I had to guess, I assume your question is [How do I plot into subplots?](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) but I might be wrong. There are also other problems with your sample code (wrong code indentation, what is symbols_list).

Comment: I appreciate that you edited the code. However, the `time` strings cannot be coerced into floats, so I still do not know what kind of output you get and how it differs from the expected output.

Comment: @Mr.T - i changed the string to float, what Im trying to do is to see multiple graphs like I see one if I call the `plt.plot(time, close)
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.show()`

Comment: I am afraid, I still don't know what you want to achieve. It sounds like 25 line plots in a 5x5 figure similar to this [2x2 example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-two-directions). Not sure, though, where `imshow()` comes into play here and how the two lists `time` and `close` are split so they give data for 25 graphs.